# What does serviceLocator() mean in GetIt?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, service-locator

I am trying to master GetIt. First I read the official documentation. Then I came to articles by different authors. Finally, I took a working code to get some practice.

And I don't understand the following. I have code that works great:

```dart
final serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;

setupServiceLocator() async {
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<Constant>(() => Constant());
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<Dio>(
    () => NetworkClient(Dio(), constant: serviceLocator()).dio,
  );

  // News
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<MainNewsBloc>(() => MainNewsBloc());
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<NewsApi>(() => NewsApi(
      dio: serviceLocator(), apiKey: serviceLocator<Constant>().apiKey));
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<NewsRepository>(() => NewsRepositoryImpl(
      newsApi: serviceLocator(), apiKey: serviceLocator<Constant>().apiKey));
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<GetRecentNewsUseCase>(
      () => GetRecentNewsUseCase(serviceLocator()));
}
```

I understand lines like:

```dart
serviceLocator.registerFactory<Constant>(() => Constant());
...
serviceLocator.registerFactory<MainNewsBloc>(() => MainNewsBloc());
```

But I don't understand lines like:

```dart
serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<NewsApi>(() => NewsApi(
      dio: serviceLocator(), apiKey: serviceLocator<Constant>().apiKey));
```

In particular, I don't understand the following:

```dart
 dio: serviceLocator(),
...
 newsApi: serviceLocator(),
...
serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<GetRecentNewsUseCase>(
      () => GetRecentNewsUseCase(serviceLocator()));
```

Why is serviceLocator() used in all these cases? What does this mean?

Of course, I should ask this question to the author of this code. But I believe that there are enough experienced programmers here to explain to me what serviceLocator() means as arguments in all these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer it's the combination of the `callable` class and type-inferance.

1. callable classes:  By `serviceLocator()` in this kind of syntax, you are invoking a method with the name `call` inside the object.

To understand this you can refer to this code example:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  const callable = CallableClass();
  callable();
}

class CallableClass {
  const CallableClass();

  void call() {
    print('invoked call method inside callable class');
  }
}
```

2. type-inferance: by specifying the return type `T` of a generic function you are passing the type parameter as `T` to that function type param.

The internal implementation of get_It looks like this:

```dart
  @override
  T call<T extends Object>({
    String? instanceName,
    dynamic param1,
    dynamic param2,
  }) {
    return get<T>(instanceName: instanceName, param1: param1, param2: param2);
  }
```

for understanding consider the following dart snipper:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  final int value = findWhereTypeIsT();
  print(value); // 10
}

T findWhereTypeIsT<T>() {
  final objects = <Object>[10, "something"];
  return objects.whereType<T>().first;
}
```

And according to get it docs: *Callable class so that you can write `GetIt.instance<MyType>` instead of  `GetIt.instance.get<MyType>`*